# Power Automorphism of P Groups

Tags: group-theory

The lower exponent p-central series for a p-group G is defined by $G=P_1(G) \geqslant P_2(G) \geqslant...\geqslant P_c(G)=I$, , where $ P_{i+1}(G)= [P_{i}(G) , G ] P_{i}(G)^{p}$ for $i \geqslant1$ and $G_i=G/P_{i}(G)$.
 If $G$ is a d generator(number of generators is d) p-group,  then we see that $AutoG_2=GL(p,d)$ Now I am looking for $PowerAuto(G_2)=?$ I tried by myself but did not able to prove it, I need a proof of this. Here
PowerAuto$(G_2)$=Power Automorphism of $(G_2)$. Power Automorphism is an automorphism which leaves every subgroup invariant

Comment: What do you call "Power Auto($G_2$) to??

Comment: Power Automorphism$(G_2)$, an automorphism which leaves every subgroup of $G_2$ invariant

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

Ok, so we have that

$$P_2(G)=[P_1(G),G]P_1(G)^p=G'G^p=\Phi(G)=\text{ the Frattini subgroup of }\;\;G$$

and from here that

$$G_2:=G/P_2(G)=G/\Phi(G)$$

and thus this group is elementary abelian, so the question could be rephrased as: in a finite dimensional group over the prime field of characteristic $\;p\;$, what automorphisms (=regular linear operators) are there that leave **every** subgroup fixed? The answer is: only the scalar multiples of it, $\;kI\;,\;\;0\neq k\in\Bbb F_p\;$ since otherwise, for an automorphism $\;T\neq kI\;$ there exists

$$0\neq v\in G_2\;\;s.t.\;\;Tv\notin\langle v\rangle\;$$

and we have thus found a subspace not $\;T$-invariant.